# Wait for child using os.system

Tags: python, shell, os.system

I use a lot of `os.system` calls to create background processes inside a for loop. How can I wait for all the background processes to end ?

`os.wait` tells me there are no child process.

ps: I am using Solaris

here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os

pids = []
NB_PROC=30

for i in xrange(NB_PROC):
        p = subprocess.Popen("(time wget http://site.com/test.php 2>&1 | grep real )&", shell=True)
        pids.insert(0,p)
        p = subprocess.Popen("(time wget http://site.com/test.php 2>&1 | grep real )&", shell=True)
        pids.insert(0,p)

for i in xrange(NB_PROC*2):
        pids[i].wait()
os.system("rm test.php*")
```

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated, try to use `subprocess` module

Comment: os.system is not deprecated it seems : http://docs.python.org/library/os.html but even by using subprocess i have the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, `os.system()` returns when the child process is finished. So there is indeed nothing for `os.wait()` to do. It is equivalent to `subprocess.call()`.

Use `subprocess.Popen()` to create background processes, and then the `wait()` or `poll()` methods of the `Popen` objects to wait for them to quit.

By default, Popen does not spawn a shell but executes the program directly. This saves resources and prevents possible shell injection attacks.

According to the documentation for `os.system()`:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function

If you want to do multiple jobs in parallel, consider using `multiprocessing`, especially the `Pool` object. It takes care of a lot of the details of farming work out over several processes.

**Edit:** Timing the execution of a program;

```
import time
import subprocess

t1 = time.clock()
t2 = time.clock()
overhead = t2-t1

t1 = time.clock()
subprocess.call(['wget', 'http://site.com/test.php'])
t2 = time.clock()
print 'elapsed time: {:.3f} seconds.'.format(t2-t1-overhead)
```

Comment: @maazza The Python script with `os.system` waits for the shell to terminate. Since the shell command ends in `&`, the shell terminates as soon as it's launched the pipeline, without waiting for it to terminate.

Comment: true ! but what about subprocess ? do you think it has the same problem ?

Comment: @maazza That's not a problem, it's just doing what you told it to. What are you tring to accomplish? If you want to time the execution of a command, just use `subprocess.call()` in between two `time.clock()` calls.

Comment: no it needs to be concurrent requests to a web server , time.clock does not help

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Stress-test a web-server? In that case I suggest you look at the requests module (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html). To parallelize that, use e.g. the `map()` method from `multiprocessing.Pool`. With that, you can even test several URLs, not just one.

Answer (score 3):

the solution was indeed in the subprocess module

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os

pids = []
NB_PROC=4
cmd="(time wget http://site.com/test.php 2>&1 | grep elapsed | cut -d ' ' -f 3)"

for i in xrange(NB_PROC):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=None,stdout=None, shell=True)
    pids.insert(0,p)
    print "request %d processed" % (i+1)


for i in xrange(NB_PROC):
    pids[i].wait()
os.system("rm test.php*")
```

switched to debian in the process but for some reason sometimes the scripts hangs while sometimes it just runs fine