# How to know if an external process has finished in python?

Tags: python, windows, terminate, external-process

I am working from a windows platform. In my python script, I can make a call to an external program in the following way:

```
os.system("C:\mainfolder\menu.exe C:\others\file1.inp C:\others\file2.inp")

os.popen("C:\mainfolder\menu.exe C:\others\file1.inp C:\others\file2.inp")

subprocess.call(["C:\mainfolder\menu.exe","C:\others\file1.inp" "C:\others\file2.inp"])
```

where:

menu.exe: is my external program.

file1 and file2: are input files to my external program.

All the above works fine. Now that my external program has finished successfully, I need to totally close it along with all the windows that are left opened by it. I have gone through lots of other posts, python documentation, etc and found commands as for example:

```
os.system("taskkill /im C:\mainfolder\menu.exe")

os.kill(proc.pid,9)

child.kill()
```

But they did not work. I spent a lot of time trying to find something that worked for me, until I realised that no matter which commands I type after, they will not be read as the computer does not know that my external program has finished. That is the reason why I can easily terminate the program from the command line anytime just by typing taskkill /im menu.exe, but not from python.

Does anybody know how to sort this out?, should I include something else when I make the call to my external program?

Comment: If the program you call opens other programs, you may not be able to do anything about that.  I'm not sure though.

Comment: Seriously?, I do not know too much about programming but I always thought that in programming everything is possible. Hope I find an answer for this:-(

Comment: If you can modify the opened programs to send a signal to your process right before/as they close (such as via DBus) you could use IPC to figure this out.

Comment: It is not true that you cannot do anything about it, it's just that the answer may be deeply hidden for windows. In linux kill with -9 switch will terminate said process and its children/parents, and I am not sure which switch of taskkill does the equivalent of that.

Comment: Actually, did you try adding /F to your taskkill?

Comment: @Puciek, If you mean typing: os.system(taskkill /f /im C:\mainfolder\menu.exe), yes, I tried it. But anything that I type after the call to my program will work, as python will not go further than that.

Comment: your problem is, that the program `menu.exe` does not terminate, so how should python know about something not happening? How do you know, when `menu.exe` finished?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I also think that is my problem. Is there anything that I can do to terminate that program automatically?, maybe changing the code from menu.exe is the only solution?, there is nothing that can be done from python? Calling the program in a different way with other additional commands?. I do not think I have the source code of menu.exe..

Comment: @Sarah: without knowing what `menu.exe` does, any advice is difficult. You could kill the program after some period of time or check for some file written or some window opened, or something else.

Comment: @Daniel: When menu.exe does all it processing, it leaves an active window that I need to close manually, once I close it, then python recognises that menu.exe has finished. Maybe killing the program after some time could work? Is there anything better that could be done?

Comment: Perhaps my problem is related with something about multithreading?. If it is not, I would really appreciate if somebody let me know it as I am really struggling to understand the python documentation of this topic..

Comment: Most of the time, I take the opposite approach. Instead of the parent killing the child, I make the child kill itself if the pid of his parent (ppid) becomes "1".

Comment: @Sarah: has nothing to do with multithreading. As I said, `menu.exe` doesn't terminate. The best way is, to wait for the opening of the message window and kill the program afterwards.

Comment: @Apero: Sorry, I am not sure how this is possible, would it be possible for you to give me a short example?.

Comment: @Daniel: Do you mean killing the program after some period of time?

Comment: For controlling it manually you could check it in the taskmanager. It helps to check whether the os.kill() worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some example code, how to detect if a program opens a window. All you need to know is the title of the message box, that `menu.exe` opens, when it is finished:

```
import subprocess
import win32gui
import time


def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Menu.exe Finished' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            proc.kill()

proc = subprocess.Popen(["C:\mainfolder\menu.exe","C:\others\file1.inp" "C:\others\file2.inp"])
while proc.poll() is None:
    win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Does this code terminate my program when it detects that there is an active window?

Comment: Terminates the program, if there is a window with a specific title.

Comment: This is a really useful code, I did not know about it. However in my case that window opens at the very beginning of the process. While my program is running, it will say: Processing, and when it finishes processing my data, it will say: Finished. The title of the window remains the same. The title of the window is the name of my program. There might be a way to extract the word finished from the window instead of the title?.

Comment: @Sarah: so that's more complicated. You have to find the window, look through all it's child-elements for some label with the text `finished`. Here's a stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500026/python-how-to-get-the-text-label-from-another-program-window

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I am still reading the link that you have provided. Regarding to your code above, does it mean that if I call my program using: proc = subprocess.Popen(["C:\mainfolder\menu.exe","C:\others\file1.inp" "C:\others\file2.inp"]), will it read the following code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a process end immediately, i.e., wait for it to end, this is a blocking call, and `os.system()` normally waits, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12071044) as well as `.communicate[0]` using subprocess [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5631764).

If you want to end a process later in your program, an asynchronous, non-blocking process, perhaps get its [pid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799419) and depending on whether `shell=True` or not that will either be the pid of the [spawned shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989942) or of the child process.

That pid can be used to end it either [immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858114) by using psutil or os, or [wait until it ends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7653316) using little cpu time, though then other tasks can be done while waiting, or threads could be used.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late to post my findings to this question as I asked it some months back but it may still be helpful for other readers.

With the help of the people who tried answering my question, especially Daniel's answer, I found out a solution for my problem. Not sure if it is the best one but I got what I was needing.

Basically instead of looking for the word "finished" on my pop up window, I looked for the results that my external program generates. If these results have been generated, it means that the program has finished so I then kill the process:

```
 proc=subprocess.Popen(["C:\mainfolder\menu.exe","C:\others\file1.inp" "C:\others\file2.inp"])
 while proc.poll() is None:
     if os.path.exists("D:\\Results_folder\\Solution.txt"):
           time.sleep(10)
           os.system('taskkill /im menu.exe')
```

Comment: You can use `Popen.pid` to get the process ID of the subprocess you have spawned. Then you can call `kill -0 PID` (if you're using Windows check how `kill` behaves there!) in a loop until it's return value becomes 0 or `None`.